# Passing variable from shell script to psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

#!/bin/sh

today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

echo $today
#20220720

psql -h myhost -U sqladmin -d trades 8787 -c "select * from recalculate_value("$today")";

When executing psql,  the $today is not getting interpreted correctly.

What is the proper way to pass the $today in the psql command line?

select * from recalculate_value('20220720') ;

Comment: Is recalculate_value('20220720') your table/ collection name?

Comment: '20220720' value will be used inside a where clause  date(trade_date)=  date('20220720')

Comment: psql "sslmode=disable dbname=trades user=sqluser hostaddr=192.168.1.10" -c "select * from stock_portfolio_buy('20220720')";  this is the sql that I would like to pass in psql.

Comment: What does "recalculate_value" do? What does `"$today"` mean for "recalculate_value"? What is your error; syntax, type or something else?